# Android Studio 4.2 don't respond when I try to open it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.2

I had to download  new version of Android Studio (4.2). Now on my computer (Mac) I have both older and newer version of Android Studio. My new version was working perfectly but since yesterday I cannot open it. I can still open my older version of Android Studio but new one is not launching. I'm only able to open new version from terminal using sudo command (but I don't want to do this us application is open from root and is causing issue when building my project.) How can I fix it? Is older version blocking my new version of Android Studio?

Comment: Sounds like you need to give admin permissions using sudo to allow permanent opening of Android Studio

Comment: Hi Jaimie, how I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to download it from here : [all versions of Android Studio](https://android-studio.en.uptodown.com/windows/versions)